# Why are these two inline-blocks not aligned?

Tags: css

These two inline-block `<div>` should be (at least, I thought they would be) aligned:

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="month">
        <div class="month-name">January</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <div class="day-number">21</div>
        <div class="day-name">Wednesday</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="button"></div>
```

I've set the height of every `<div>` with a pixel precision:

```css
.calendar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 74px;
}
.calendar .month {
    background-color: firebrick;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.calendar .month-name {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 26px;
}
.calendar .day {
    background-color: linen;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.calendar .day .day-number {
    color: black;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}
.calendar .day .day-name {
    color: darkgray;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 18px;
}

.button {
    background-color: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 74px;
}
```

But this produces the following result:

[image: inline-block]

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2cp6/) of this code.

This is driving me crazy, but the result is consistent across several browsers, so I must be doing something wrong.

Can anyone explain why, and provide a fix?

Comment: @Oriol "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". No, I asked the question before. Better mark the other one as duplicate of this one?

Comment: Yes, your question is older, but the other question is more "popular": 3953 vs 155 views, 10 vs 1 upvotes, 1 vs 0 favorites, 34 vs 5 upvotes in the answers. Feel free to discuss it in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you disagree.

Comment: Kind of makes sense, I guess. Still, it's quite rude to get a message "This question has been asked before"; the message could be improved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do `vertical-align:top` on whatever has inline-block.

`.calendar { vertical-align: top; }`

Explanation: inline-blocks are still "in-line" and the vertical alignment is baseline meaning they aren't consistent and it will vary on their height, top makes them consistently start at the top.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why?

Comment: inline-blocks are still "in-line" and the vertical alignment is baseline meaning they aren't consistent and it will vary on their height, `top` makes them consistently start at the top.

Answer (score 4):

Set the vertical align to top on the calendar div

```
.calendar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 74px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s2cp6/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why?

Comment: Because the default vertical alignment is baseline, and you need them top aligned.

Comment: Thanks, your answers being equivalent, I've accepted one and upvoted the other!